# Unable to edit Visualforce pages/components in Developer Console

Tags: visualforce, developer-console

Over the last couple of months, across all orgs used by my development team, we have noticed that the Developer Console refuses to allow anybody to save changes made to Visualforce pages or components. Whenever you try to save, an issue with no problem description shows up in the Problems panel attached to line 1 of the page/component. This happens every single time, regardless of any actual changes being made (I can add and delete a whitespace, and it still won't allow me to save). We noticed this problem during Summer '13, and it is still happening after our upgrade to Winter '14.

Anybody else experiencing this issue, or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced this too in the Developer's Console, and the errors I encounter mention that there is an issue with either the `ContainerId` or the `DeploymentId`.

If it is the `DeploymentId`, there is an easy fix.  Copy your code (**always** make sure you **copy your code** if you are having trouble with the Dev Console...), then go to any Salesforce record and paste the bad `DeploymentId`, then click  <kbd>Delete</kbd> .

Example:

> `DeploymentId` = `1drc00000007ngjAAA`
>
> URL = https://cs14.salesforce.com/1drc00000007ngjAAA

You'll get a page that looks like this:

[image: What it a "Deployment" Record Looks like]

If the issue purely concerns a `ContainerId`, then I don't know of an easy fix.  When this has happened to me, the only fix I found was to edit my Class in the Class record itself.

( <kbd>Develop</kbd>  ➽  <kbd>Apex Classes</kbd>  ➽ Your_Class)

---

As a side note, having different developers working on VF Page **AND** the Controller simultaneously can be a big headache because (many, many times) I've had my Controller's changes overwritten when the developer working on the VF page commits a change without making sure they had the up-to-date controller.

I highly recommend trying to nail down the Controller first before working on the VF Page, and if this is not possible, both developers need to have enough wherewithal to know which version of the controller they are working with (so not to overwrite the Controller with an old version resulting in lost work).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the problem still bothers you after 2 and half years, but here is what I found. If an apex:component has an attribute which is an apex class (type="a custom class name"), it must have a controller, otherwise the exact problem would happen. Any VF page that uses this component gets the same issue too.

For example, part of my original code for the component was like below:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="myQuery" type="Class_CustomQuery" required="required" description="query result class" />
    <apex:outputText value="<b>{!myQuery.QueryName}</b>&nbsp;{!myQuery.ResultCount}" escape="false" />
...
```

This actually worked fine but gave the exact issue of "Problems on Line 1 but no description" in developer console.

To solve this, a controller class is needed, even a dummy one. Here is the fixed version:

The controller:

```
public class ComController_CustomQuery {

    private Class_CustomQuery cqQuery;   
    public Class_CustomQuery myQuery
    {
       get{
           return cqQuery;
       }
       set{
           cqQuery=value;
       }
    }
}
```

The component:

```
<apex:component controller="ComController_CustomQuery">
<apex:attribute name="myQR" type="Class_CustomQuery" required="required" assignTo="{!myQuery}"  description="query result class" />

<apex:outputText value="<b>{!myQuery.QueryName}</b>&nbsp;{!myQuery.ResultCount}" escape="false" />
...
```

No more complaints from the developer console after the change.

Answer (score 0):

try opening it in a different editor (force.com ide, mavensmate). I believe you'll find a dependent class compilation issue. i've noticed that sometimes the dev console fails to display details of those.

Comment: Nope, there are no actual problems. As I said, we've been living with this for months, using external editors as a work-around. The pages function just fine and all org code compiles and is stable, the console just simply refuses to allow us to edit ANY VF, in ANY of our packages...

Comment: The Compile All Classes link on the Apex Classes page is a quick way to find compilation issues in existing code.

Comment: Yep, been there numerous times and everything checks out. Still able to save with no trouble from the IDE, still completely unable to save from Dev Console

Comment: tried various user profiles?

Comment: stupid question, but you are trying this in a sandbox, or dev org correct?

Comment: System admin profile.
Both sandbox and development org